# How do i manage startActivityForResult on Android?

Tags: android

In my activity, I'm calling a second activity from the main activity by startActivityForResult. In my second activity there are some methods that finish this activity (maybe without result), however, just one of them return a result.

For example, from the main activity, I call a second one. In this activity I'm checking some features of handset such as does it have a camera. If it doesn't have then I'll close this activity. Also, during the preparation of MediaRecorder or MediaPlayer if a problem happens then I'll close this activity.

If its device has a camera and recording is done completely, then after recording a video if a user clicks on the done button then I'll send the result (address of the recorded video) back to main activity.

How do I check the result from the main activity?

Comment: See this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Answer (score 1):

**In the main activity you should have this :**

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // actions that will happen when the button is pressed:

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
});
```

And in the second activity you should pass result like  position of the list item from the RecyclerView clicked, **like this :**

```
ExampleClickAdapter clickAdapter = new ExampleClickAdapter(yourObjects);
clickAdapter.setOnEntryClickListener(new ExampleClickAdapter.OnEntryClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onEntryClick(View view, int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("pos", position);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
});
recyclerView.setAdapter(clickAdapter);
```

And in the main activity you should have a method for get result , **this is your method :**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            int result = data.getIntExtra("pos");
            // do something with the result

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // some stuff that will happen if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of good result, in the `SecondActivity` could be:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, getIntent());
finish();
```

This way, you can "reply", from the `SecondActivity` that the task was successfull, and the intent can carry your information.

And then, in your `FirstActivity`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode==YOUR_REQUEST_CODE && Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode) {
        // Stuff went fine
    }
}
```